# getPastEvents cannot handle multiple requests?

Tags: web3js, events, quorum

When I send about 100-120 requests in async, it is fine, the event will give me a response. But above 150 or so, I get "Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Web3JS 1.2.1

Geth Info:
Version: 1.8.12-stable
Git Commit: bb0261036b768b26e7f63ebecdb5ae32c76f99bb
Quorum Version: 2.2.1

Comment: How many nodes are you using?

Comment: Currently using 5 nodes

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: contractInstance.getPastEvents('create', {
      filter: { cid: addr, date: date, slot: slot},
      fromBlock: 0,
      toBlock: 'latest'
    }, function (error, event) {})

Comment: This code seems to be fine. Can you send the complete code?

Comment: Not really much more to it, it is inside an API that passes the arguments for the filter.

Comment: Is the performance better when you replace the getPastEvents with a simple transaction of a few wei.

Comment: Normal transactions are working fine, it only this getPastEvents that are not able to handle the async load

Answer (score 2):

Geth is an ethereum client but it is not a high performance RPC server.

To resolve some calls like getPastEvents it has to traverse a lots of history. It was never designed to respond to thousands of queries per second.

If you want to achieve such performance it is better to store the events you are interested in a suitable database.

Comment: Pooling the Data once and then saving it in DB seems like a proper solution.

Comment: would it be the same for a function to get data? Query via a function that gets the data from the index